# Question about topological monoid maps

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, semigroups-and-monoids, reference-request

Let Mon be the category of topological monoids. I am happy to work with the model structure mentioned here:

[Model Structure/Homotopy Pushouts in topological monoids?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11059/model-structure-homotopy-pushouts-in-topological-monoids).

I'm looking for a reference for the following statement, which I believe to be true.
 Suppose  $X$ and $Y$ are topological monoids, with $X$ cofibrant, and $Y$ group-like.

**Assertion:** The map of spaces

$$
\text{monoid-maps}(X,Y) \to \text{maps}_\ast(BX,BY)
$$

is a weak homotopy equivalence.

My guess is that one could prove this by induction,
using the fact that $X$ is a retract of an object given by attaching free things. For example, here is a verification of the statement when $X = FU$, the
free monoid on the points of a based space $U$. In this case,

$$
\text{monoid-maps}(FU,Y)  = \text{maps}_\ast(U,Y) ,
$$

whereas
$$
\text{maps}_*(BFU,BY) \simeq \text{maps}_\ast(\Sigma U,BY)
$$
using, say James theorem $FU \simeq \Omega\Sigma U$. Since $Y$ is group-like, we
have $Y \simeq \Omega BY$ and we get

$$
\text{maps}_*(\Sigma U,BY) \simeq \text{maps}_\ast(U,Y) 
$$
verifying the assertion in this special case.

More generally, it seems to me that if $X = \text{colim}(X_0 \leftarrow FA \to FB)$
where $(B,A)$ is a cofibration pair (with the colimit taken in topological monoids), 
and if the assertion is true for $X_0$ then it 
is also true for $X$ using the above and by noting that (i) function spaces convert pushouts in the domain to pullbacks and (ii) the classifying space functor preserves homotopy pushouts.  This would then give the inductive step.

*Added Later:* I'd like to reiterate that I'm really looking for a decent reference.

Comment: I hesitate to continue to add things, so I'll just leave this as a comment... But it just occurred to me that the following could work and would be more elementary: (i) The functor monoids--->spaces preserves and reflects geometric realizations of simplicial objects (I think you can prove this directly, it's the homotopy version of saying monoids are algebras for a monad), (ii) the natural map $\vert F^{\bullet}X\vert \rightarrow X$ from the free resolution of $X$ is a weak equivalence, (iii) B commutes with geometric realizations, (iv) you've already proven the result for free things. 

Comment: (The only place I can see potential trouble is some sort of cofibrancy issue. Sorry I am of limited use! I hope someone comes along and adds a decent answer.)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT 2: Sorry about the confusion, I will try to be careful now, and I'll put some comments at the end to clear up the business about adjoints etc. Here's what we're going to do.

We'd like to show that
$$
\text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X, Y) \rightarrow \text{Map}_{Spaces_*}(BX, BY)
$$
is an equivalence when $X$ is cofibrant and $Y$ is grouplike. The strategy will be to consider the string
$$
\text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X,Y) \rightarrow \text{Map}_{\text{Spaces}_*}(BX,BY) \rightarrow \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(\Omega'BX, \Omega'BY) \rightarrow 
$$

$$
\text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X, \Omega'BY) \cong \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X,Y)
$$
where $\Omega'$ denotes the Moore loop space (strictly associative multiplication), and show that the composite is homotopic to the identity. This clearly reduces down to showing that the third map is a weak equivalence, since I may as well have started the string with the inverse of the last equivalence ($\Omega' BY$ and $Y$ are interchangeable).

So we want to show that
$$
\text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(\Omega'BX, \Omega'BY) \rightarrow \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X, \Omega'BY)
$$
is a weak equivalence when $X$ is cofibrant ($Y$ can be arbitrary).

We will prove this by showing that these two spaces represent the same functor on the homotopy category of spaces, the fundamental fact being that the natural map $\Omega'B Y \rightarrow \Omega'B\Omega'B Y$ is a weak equivalence.

Given a map $K \rightarrow \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X, \Omega'BY)$ we get a map $K \rightarrow \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(\Omega'BX, \Omega'B\Omega'BY)$, and composing with the natural weak equivalence gives us a map $K \rightarrow \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(\Omega'BX, \Omega'BY)$. One can check that composition gives back the original map, up to homotopy. This proves surjectivity of

$$
\text{Map}_{h\text{Spaces}}(K, \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(\Omega'BX, \Omega'BY)) \rightarrow \text{Map}_{h\text{Spaces}}(K, \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X, \Omega'BY))
$$
to get injectivity just note that we can recover the original value by applying $\Omega B'$ and using the weak equivalence again.

This completes the proof.

---

In my "second edition" I erroneously stated that there was a left adjoint to the inclusion of group-like topological monoids into monoids. Ricardo gracefully explains why this can't be true. However, it is a consequence of the above argument that there is a homotopical left adjoint, namely $\Omega'B$. (We've shown that the image of $\Omega'B$ is a homotopically reflective subcategory, and so all that's left is to note that the essential image is all group-like topological monoids.)

I've also erased the original answer, since it seems silly now that we have this one.

A reference for the argument I gave that basically showed that $\Omega'B$ was a localization functor can be found in *Higher Topos Theory* Proposition 5.2.7.4. Lots more love can be found throughout *Higher Algebra*; one can, for example, deduce a similar statement about $\mathbb{E}_1$-spaces in general, which actually implies this result since the inclusion of monoids into $\mathbb{E}_1$-spaces is an equivalence of $\infty$-categories.

Hopefully this is all correct now! Let me know if there's still errors.

Comment: (Your cofibrancy condition is used to make sure that the mapping space in the actual model category agrees with the "derived" mapping space; sorry, I forgot to mention that.)

Comment: @Dylan: your proof looks correct, but it seems way too high tech. Doesn't the sketch I provide above look somewhat simpler? Isn't there a sketch of this sort somewhere in the literature?

Anyway, I'm happy though that you mentioned Lurie's equivalence: 
$\text{Monoids} \to \text{Mon}_{\Bbb E_1}$, which is also of use to me.

Comment: @John: That equivalence was certainly known before Lurie, it says that $\mathbb{E}_1$-spaces can be "strictified". For group-like things this is clear using the Moore-loops model for a loop spaces.

I'll take a look at your proposed proof in a second; I chose the high tech route since that's the only place where I knew of references :)

Comment: I think if you wanted to do this low-tech the key point is still the combination of the facts (i) group completion is left adjoint to the forgetful functor to monoids, (ii) taking loops gives an equivalence between connected spaces and group-like $\mathbb{E}_1$-spaces. Maybe you can replace (ii) with taking Moore loops and getting group-like topological monoids, so you don't have to mention A-infty stuff, then you're down to proving (i). Maybe you can just prove this directly?

Comment: ("group-completion" means $\Omega B$, above... but I guess a better thing would've been to say "show that $\Omega B$ agrees with group-completion" where group-completion means the adjoint to the inclusion.) 

Comment: Actually, yeah, that's much nicer. Let $\Omega'$ be "Moore loops" so that it lands in group-like topological monoids. Then $\Omega'B$ is (up to homotopy) left adjoint to the inclusion of group-like topological monoids because... (i) its essenitally surjective onto group-like topological monoids, and (ii) it is idempotent ($\Omega'B\Omega'B \cong \Omega'B$). (in inftycategory world the fact that this implies $\Omega'B$ is group completion from uniqueness of adjoints and HTT Prop. 5.2.7.4). I'm sure this can be made precise with model category language but I dunno how :P

Comment: Dylan, referring to the statement that E1 spaces can be strictified---Yes, of course: that part is Boardman and Vogt. But the statement about mapping spaces is nowhere to be found in their tome. Unless I'm mistaken think the literature is very scant in this regard. There is a related result of Fuchs (1965!), the proof of which is unreadable: the map $\text{Mon}_{A_\infty}(X,Y)\to \text{Top}_∗(BX,BY)$ is a weak equivalence when $Y$ is group-like. That proof is unreadable. Your (ii), is tantamount to what Fuch's was trying to do. The classical literature on this is not well-written.

Comment: In your new argument you write: monoid-maps(BX,BY)≅monoid-maps(Ω′BX,Ω′BY). This is a typo I believe. I think the left side is supposed to be $\text{maps}_*(BX,BY)$. 

Comment: And yes, your new proof is more elementary once you've gotten the simplicially enriched Quillen equivalence. 

Comment: @Dylan: I am afraid the inclusion of the full subcategory of group-like monoids in the category of monoids in topological spaces does *not* have a left adjoint. This is because a reflective subcategory of a complete category is complete, and the inclusion preserves limits. Now observe that there are limits of group-like monoids which are not group-like. For example, the pullback of $[0,+\infty) \to S^1 \leftarrow 1$ (where the map $[0,+\infty) \to S^1$ is given by complex exponential) in the category of topological monoids is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}$, which is not group-like.

Comment: @Ricardo: Oh dear, I guess it only admits a homotopical adjoint... (Notice that the pullback you write down is not a homotopy pullback, which I think is precisely the issue?). I'll try to sort this out by the end of the day. Sorry for my silliness- I was expecting someone wiser to come along and give a better answer anyway :P

Comment: @Dylan: I don't understand why you write $\text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X, \Omega'BY) \cong \text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X,Y)$.  It's at best a weak equivalence. Secondly, why is the map $Y\to \Omega' BY$ a monoid map. It's an $A_\infty$-map, I agree, but I doubt it's a monoid map. Am I missing something?

Comment: $\cong$ means "weak equivalence" for me, should've made that clear. And you're right, however it follows from the aforementioned equivalence of $\infty$-categories between monoids and $\mathbb{E}_1$-spaces that the map is homotopic to a monoid map (and I think the space of such choices is contractible, so pick any one you like.)

Comment: @Dylan: in other words, your second proof isn't really simpler than your first one. Right? IMO there should be no need to prove the statement by passing through $\Bbb E_1$-spaces---that's auxiliary. 

By the way, what is the first (historical) reference for the statement $\text{Map}_{\text{Mon}}(X,Y) \to \text{Map}_{E_1\text{-Mon}}(X,Y)$ is an equivalence when $X$ is cofibrant? You said that it is older than Lurie. 

Comment: @John: I agree with you... I mean maybe one could write down an explicit map $Y \rightarrow \Omega'BY$ that's a monoid map, without using the big result? I feel like it's a matter of choosing nice enough models for things more than anything...

I don't actually know of a reference, I just thought it was at least folklore from long before- I could be wrong (I'm not the person to ask).

