# The model category structure on $\mathbf{TMon}$

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, higher-category-theory, model-categories

I ask this question here since I asked it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310262/the-model-category-structure-on-tmon-and-homotopy-colimits) on Math.SE, and got no answers after a week of a bounty offer.

I am trying to understand the homotopy colimit of a diagram of topological monoids, and whether there is an explicit construction of this object (even in the case of simple pushout diagrams).

Let **TMon** denote the category of well-pointed topological monoids which have the homotopy types of cell complexes.

**TMon** can be equipped with a model category structure where the fibrations and weak equivalences are the (Serre) fibrations and weak equivalences of the underlying topological spaces - this comes from section $3$ of the paper

> R. Schwänzl and R.M. Vogt, *The categories of $A_\infty$- and $E_\infty$-monoids and ring spaces as closed simplicial and topological model categories*, Arch. Math **56** (1991) pp 405–411, doi:[10.1007/BF01198229](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01198229).

Cofibrations are the morphisms which have the appropriate lifting property.

I wish to understand what the homotopy colimit of a diagram of topological monoids is. One way of approaching this is to take the colimit of the cofibrant replacement of the diagram in question. This involves (firstly) understanding cofibrations in **TMon**.

I struggle with this. I really have no intuition for what a cofibration in this category is at all. This is the first thing preventing me from understanding homotopy colimits of diagrams in **TMon**.

> **Question:**
>
> Are there constructions of the homotopy colimit in **TMon** in the case of
> simple diagrams? For example, if a diagram has morphisms which are all
> inclusions on the level of topological spaces? Or if the diagram is Reedy? Or under
> any other sufficiently nice assumptions?

Comment: Cofibrations in $TMon$ are going to be more specific: they will be retracts of "cellular maps", i.e., of maps built by iteratively attaching cells.  A cell will be something of the form $F(S^{n-1})\to F(D^n)$, where $F$ is the free monoid on a space.  Thus, the "simplest" examples of cofibrant objects are discrete *free* monoids.

Comment: Thanks for your comment - I'm a bit of a beginner with this. Is it possible for you to elaborate a little on why cofibrations should be retracts of such maps, or why a "cell" is what you give above?

Comment: It's an example of a general formalism for constructing model category structures by "lifting".  Here we are lifting the usual model structure on spaces to $TMon$: so the we's and fib's of TMon are "detected" by the forgetful structure to spaces.  Formally, the left adjoint $F$ to the forgetful functor will preserve cofibrations and trivial cofibrations.  In particular, it must supply a large collection of cofibrations in TMon, which can be used to "build" all cofibrations.

Comment: Key phrases here are "cofibrantly generated model category" and "tranferred model structure": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cofibrantly+generated+model+category, https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/transferred+model+structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question:

[Model Structure/Homotopy Pushouts in topological monoids?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/11059/model-structure-homotopy-pushouts-in-topological-monoids)

especially the answer by John Francis.

First of all, monoids have classifying spaces, and so a pushout 
diagram $M_1\gets M_0 \to M_2$ of monoids and monoid maps gives rise to 
a pushout diagram $BM_1 \gets BM_0 \to BM_2$, and the claim is that, 
essentially, 
$$
\mathrm{hocolim}_{\mathbf{TMon}}( M_1\gets M_0 \to M_2 )  = \Omega (
\mathrm{colim}_{\mathbf{T}} (BM_1 \gets BM_0 \to BM_2 ))  .
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it somehow took me a long time to see this.